# S3 File Copy Access Denied on the console but works with CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I get an Access Denied Error on AWS console when I try to copy or move files between folders within the same bucket.

However, same action works on the AWS CLI. The error message on the UI is not descriptive. I tried using CloudTrail and allowed all the actions which were logged with Access Denied message. Still the issue persists.

How do I troubleshoot this non-descriptive message on the UI?

I ended up adding below permissions but didn't work so far:

```
                - s3:ListBucket
                - s3:GetBucketLocation
                - s3:GetObject
                - s3:PutObject
                - s3:AbortMultipartUpload
                - s3:GetBucketOwnershipControls
                - s3:GetObjectTagging
                - s3:PutObjectTagging
                - s3:GetBucketVersioning
                - s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration
                - s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration
                - s3:DeleteObject
```

[image]

Comment: Are you signed in to the same account in the gui and cli?

Comment: Yes, assumed the same role on the console and cli. How can I get a more descriptive error message?

Comment: Solution was to allow s3:GetObjectAcl and s3:PutObjectAcl